# Overflow to the left?

Tags: css

Is it possible to set a horizontal scrolling feature so that it scrolls to (overflow, I'm assuming, unless there is another way) the left as well as the right. Sort of like this picture:

[a horizontal scrolling feature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiBzj.jpg)

... except I want to load the object just like it is in that photo but have other objects (images rather than the divs pictured) back behind to the left of that first object), so you can scroll to unseen things in both directions.

EDIT: in response to some of the people offering to help here (thanks), I have composed a fiddle (in the comments below). The hope is that I could load this horizontal feature with the blue-border box at far left (on initial load) and people could scroll back or forth). I'd prefer (but I'll take either one) it to be marked to load on that box rather than css it so it would load after a certain width or something like that, because I want to it to function this way universally (regardless of how many objects are hidden to the left) but, again, I'll take either solution, because I can probably make it work with either.

Comment: And how do you want to scroll without scrollbars?

Comment: Does the following link appear close to your requirement?http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/jquery_thumbnail_scroller_multiple.html

Comment: I was thinking something like this, but the far left image would be the blue border (on load), so you could scroll back or forth http://jsfiddle.net/JMunce/58qnaett/

Comment: Update: I've been experimenting with scroll points (seems I can't demonstrate with fiddle because I can't load the page with the #whatever exension). What I've done is put a div around an object in the horizontal series -- make the div id of "loadhere" and display:inline it. Then I link to the page with domain/page#loadhere . What I've achieved, though, is it will load with that div in the picture, but not at the far left (it'll load it at the far right if it's off the usual load screen).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick mockup of something like that. It can be extended to use scroll events. Used jquery but it can be done in pure js too. Just made the body hide the overflow like this

```
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

I have buttons to move it around but as I said you can do it with scroll events too.

```
function left () {
    var div = document.getElementById('scrollContainer');
    $(div).animate({ "right": "+=100px" }, 500);
}

function right () {
    var div = document.getElementById('scrollContainer');
    $(div).animate({ "right": "-=100px" }, 500);
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hna6jkzk/

And obviously the divs can be images too.

A fiddle with no JS and visible scrollbar: http://jsfiddle.net/hna6jkzk/1/

A fiddle with no JS and hidden scrollbar: http://jsfiddle.net/hna6jkzk/2/

Comment: This is pretty groovy, although I'd prefer to avoid javascript if at all possible (for the sake of the African browswers, etc). I was thinking something like this http://jsfiddle.net/JMunce/58qnaett/ but the initial load would display blue-border at the far left on page load (but you could scroll back further left)

Comment: @JamesFrankHaleavy I have updated answer with some examples that use no javascript and either show a scrollbar or hide it. The blue border can be added using tab index attributes on the divs/images and the :focus pseudo selector

Comment: Hi @atheistP3ace Thanks I looked but are these loading in a certain position for you? For me, when I load the fiddle pages, they just load with the top left box at the top left (in other words, the request -- loading a box somewhere else in the series in the top-left position initially, so you can scroll forward or back from it-- isn't there).

Comment: @JamesFrankHaleavy hi sorry maybe I misunderstood. You want to load it with it already scrolled to the left?

Comment: Hi @athiestP3ace Yes, correct. I am able to display a horizontal sliding feature with multiple elements in a row, but I want to load the page so that not-the-first-object-in-series shows in the far-left position right away, then the user can scroll to the right (as is normal and already accomplished) but ALSO can scroll backwards to the left.

Comment: @JamesFrankHaleavy ok I understand. Not at computer right now but when I am I will update fiddle to show you how to do it in a little bit.

Comment: Oh ok, great. I'll look forward to it! @athiestP3ace

Comment: @JamesFrankHaleavy So I believe that its impossible to set the scroll using only CSS and HTML. You may be able to pull it off using autofocus attribute but that won't work in every browser. Without a complicated set of HTML and CSS I don't think you can do what you want and even then you won't get everything working the way you want. To truly implement everything you want javascript may be required.